# UIImage not showing on iPhone 5 but shows up on all other

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I can get the image to show up on all the iPhone simulators except not on the iPhone 5 simulator and not on the iPhone 5 hardware.  Here is the code:

```
 -(void) populateIconScroller{
int i = 0;
for( i = 0; i < 7; i++){
    UIImageView *iconView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"test.jpg"]];
    iconView.frame = CGRectMake(48*i+2, 2, 48, 48);
    [self.IconScroller addSubview:iconView];        
}
self.IconScroller.contentSize = CGSizeMake( 48*i+2,48);  
}
```

I have tried PNG and JPG, and I have tried using the @2x convention all with the same result.
Any clues would be greatly appreciated...thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check the capitalisation of the `test.jpg` asset. If it's incorrect (e.g. it's `Test.jpg`) then it'll work on the simulator and not the device.

Comment: nope - read about that and already checked it...also it doesn't work on the iPhone 5 simulator just the others.